# Snapshot of the current time

Tags: vb.net

Displaying the time is very simple. What I am trying to do is to take a snapshot of the current time and display it in a label so later I can take the length between the start and end call. For instance

12:23  12:43 = 00:20 length.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You forgot to ask one.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Question: How can I display the snapshot of the time when I clicked the button in a label.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include the question there, not put it in comments where people can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

put this in the initization of your form (Load event)

```
Label1.text = Now
```

That is sort of sloppy though, better off to put it in a Date variable in your forms member variable (global) area

```
Public StartTime As Date = Now

Public ReadOnly Property Elapsed As TimeSpan
    Get
        Return Now - StartTime
    End Get
End Property
```

This is a real question eh?

Comment: You should wait until there's an actual question asked before posting it. If the question finally asked is different than what you've answered, it can cost you rep with the downvotes you'll receive.

Comment: @KenWhite: Not a problem at all. Delete your answer and post a new one. Downvotes cleared, everybody's happy.

Comment: @Neolisk: Until you're doing it often enough for the mods to notice and your repeated deletions get your account suspended or banned. Then it's a problem, right?

Comment: @KenWhite: I don't see why this is a violation of the terms. They ask a different question, you provide a different answer. Note that it really is a different answer and should be legally considered as such. BTW, Stackoverflow allows you to have multiple answers to the same question, each having their own reputation count.

Comment: @Neolisk: Gee, thanks for the lesson on how SO works. ;-) While you can post multiple answers, and each answer does indeed accrue its own points, they're all tied to the same user account. Repeated posting and deleting of answers that are wrong draws flags and can result in suspension (as I've already said).

Comment: Well Brad didn't officially ask a question, he pointed out what he wanted to do. You can infer the question from that. I'd rather give the guy something to help him out (since he is clearly not a hard core programmer, I'm sure any help is good help)

Comment: @KenWhite: Then the current system needs improvement. There is nothing wrong with deleting the answer, which was wrongfully downvoted. If we stimulate people to refrain from answering in the fear of getting downvoted, we would end up having no answers at all. With how bad the question is, I agree with DarrenMB that some answer is better than no answer at all.

Comment: @DarrenMB: And if you answer a non-asked question and happen to guess correctly, there's absolutely no incentive for the poster to come back and improve it, making it meaningless to future readers because there's no content to search. The goal here is to help many people by providing a resource, not one person; that's the reason we have a means of closing questions that are too localized. "Any help is good help" is not a useful resource.

Comment: @Neolisk: No, the system is working as designed. Discouraging people from posting wild guesses over and over because they don't bother to read the questions is good, and discouraging people from posting answers to questions not asked means that questions get improved by the posters because they need to do so in order to get help, and those improved questions make them useful to others in the future. The goal here is not to provide customized, specialty answers to localized questions; it's to provide a resource that is useful to many people at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. It is meant exactly for that:

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time.

Declare a form level variable, and [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start.aspx) the StopWatch. Then retrieve time elapsed via [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) property. It returns a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), which you can format using [this ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) overload.

Comment: I did it the other way around because he wanted access to the Start Time. Figured it is easier to calculate elapsed from start time then to calculate start time from Elapsed.

Comment: @DarrenMB: Well, you basically replicated the functionality of StopWatch class. I used to be doing the same before I learnt about it. Nothing wrong with it, but I prefer using specific classes, provided they are standard .NET, as in this case.